# Simple Dojo detect OS, browser, and browser version issue

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have been messing around with Dojo for a couple of days and I have some code at 
https://gist.github.com/3763422

that works but I would rather just have one 
   paragraph tag with an id that gets the values of the browser name that is inside of that array depending on what sniff has detected. I have tried various things but nothing seems to work.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You're better off posting a jsfiddle. You should show your code here.

Comment: Still hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: You see all those <dt>'s with isIe, isMoz etc. I just want to have one     paragraph tag with an id that just inserts the value of /sniff from that array without having the need for all of those <dt>'s

Comment: technically taking the name of the browser being picked out of that array putting it into a paragraph with an id i.e.                arrayUtil.forEach(["ie", "mozilla", "ff", "opera", "webkit",       "chrome"], function(n){
         dom.byId("browserName").innerHTML = n; // but this kills my      other function
       });

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
 arrayUtil.forEach(["ie", "mozilla", "ff", "opera", "webkit", "chrome"], function(n){
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = makeFancyAnswer(n);
    dom.byId("myParagraph").appendChild(p);
 });
```

This will create a number of paragraphs inside the node myParagraph

Comment: Hi Juan,Agreed. But, you cannot find out what O/S you are in with /sniff

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need Dojo to do this. Just explore `navigator` object. Type in JavaScript Console `navigator` and hit enter.

It should give you something like this:

```
Navigator
  appCodeName: "Mozilla"
  appName: "Netscape"
  appVersion: "5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17"
  cookieEnabled: true
  doNotTrack: null
  geolocation: Geolocation
  language: "en-US"
  mimeTypes: MimeTypeArray
  onLine: true
  platform: "MacIntel"
  plugins: PluginArray
  product: "Gecko"
  productSub: "20030107"
  userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17"
  vendor: "Google Inc."
  vendorSub: ""
```

What is the standard and what is not you can find at MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator